# Ubuntu Bash Menu Script with Arguments

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have to write a bash menu script that can run other scripts but I can't pass arguments for scripts, what should I do? That is my code

```
 #!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            ./script1.sh
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            ./script2.sh
            ;;
        "Option 3")
            ./script3.sh
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```

How can I pass arguments for script1.sh, script2.sh and script3.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send arguments when calling the script in the case statement. For example, using your code:

```
#!/bin/bash                                      
# Bash Menu Script Example                       
                                                 
PS3='Please enter your choice: '                 
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"                    
do                                               
    case $opt in                                 
        "Option 1")                              
            ./script1.sh HelloWorld              
            ;;                                   
        "Option 2")                              
            ./script2.sh                         
            ;;                                   
        "Option 3")                              
            ./script3.sh                         
            ;;                                   
        "Quit")                                  
            break                                
            ;;                                   
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;        
    esac                                         
done
```

./script1 looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
```

And this is the result of using your code and choose the first option.

```
[20:06:18][/] sh test.sh
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
3) Option 3
4) Quit
Please enter your choice: 1
HelloWorld
```